# Adding a TapGestureRecognizer to a UITableView backgroundView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

in my `UITableView` I have a contentInset on top and I do have a backgroundView with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that I would like to work like a button.
So if the user scrolls to the top, the backgroundView is visible and a tap on it should do something.

Unfortunately the tableView does not pass the touch through... Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks, Georg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by not using `UIEdgeInsets` but by adding a transparent `UIButton` as the tableview's headerview.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableView will catch all events on the screen, in my mind it is not possible without disable the tableView. Maybe by adding a ghost button on the tableView which will be enabled when the user scrolls to the top.